# Display next features in UML use case Diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

Is there any standard to display features(use cases) that I want to add to system in next version in `use case` diagram?Or I have to display them for example with specific color,shape or ... ?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530127/can-a-single-use-case-be-partially-implemented-or-implemented-over-several-phas/28531668#28531668

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard here.

What I do in such cases is to create a profile that contains stereotyped elements like `<<enhancement>>` `<<feature request>>` etc. which simply extend the `class` meta class. I link them via a (`<<trace>>` stereotyped) `dependency` to the relevant element (like e.g. use cases).

The advantage is that I can add tagged values where I can set additional information like `target build`, `responsible`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, there is no standard.

Using colors is a handy approach because changes are visible at a glance e. g. when shown in presentations. Assuming of course that you are not yet using colors for other semantic purposes.

You can also use UML notes.

Generally it makes sense to have diagrams versioned, so you can trace back diagram and model changes.

Some tools allow to store a version in the elements' metadata but you need to check where these can be used, because they are not necessarily visible in your diagrams as well.